# How to use my variables.scss in component <style>in vite vue 3

Tags: typescript, vue.js, sass, vuejs3, vite

`vite.config.ts`

[image: vite.config.js]

Styles in my component

[image: styles in my component]

`main.ts`

[image: main.ts]

I tried using the rules...

[image: i tried to use these rules]`

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe

1、

```
// component
<style lang="scss">
 @import "../../../assets/variable.scss";
</style
```

2、

```
// main.ts
import './assets/variable.scss'
```

3、

```
// vite.config.ts
preprocessorOptions: {
   scss: {
     additionalData: '@use "@/assets/variable.scss"as *;'
   }
}
```

Use any one of them

Comment: The 1st advise is working, thank you